# Keep null values as '' after creating new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have the following table:

```
cats
----------------------------------
name      owner     no_of_kittens
----------------------------------
bob       hanna     1
tip       frank     
spark     george    6
lucky     rita      
lady      terry     3
----------------------------------
```

I want to create a new table the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE cats_with_kittens (
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  no_of_kittens VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO cats_with_kittens
SELECT name, count(no_of_kittens)
FROM cats
GROUP BY name;
```

The problem is that in the resulting table, the no_of_kittens values of tip and lucky is 1 instead of empty string as in the initial table.

Is there a way to create the table so that values with no no_of_kittens is empty string ''?

Comment: Why use a string column to store a count (which is an integer number)?

Comment: Don't use `VARCHAR` to store numbers. It would lead to a lot of problems down the road.

Comment: Better still; don't store derived data

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` will also count empty string, you can add `case` express to make it non-countable  :

```
SELECT name, COUNT(CASE WHEN no_of_kittens <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_of_kittens 
FROM cats
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to insert empty string instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO cats_with_kittens
SELECT name, case when count(no_of_kittens) = 0 then '' 
                  else count(no_of_kittens) 
             end
FROM cats
GROUP BY name;
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=477f5f9b7d2a9bc369be3017fd63c266)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=248e9150457ff27ec172cf324d3d936e

Comment: I removed my downvote, but I still think the database model is wrong.

Comment: I agre with you, my first answer was : `no_of_kittens int default null` or default 0. And then insert count values